# How to get NSString "No Service" in status bar iphone

Tags: ios, uistatusbar

I have problem with detect sim, i was used CTCarry but not dectect when device "No Service" , Please help me how to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Reachability` class from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html):

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
switch(status) {
    case NotReachable:
        return @"No Service";
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
        ...
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [`SCNetworkReachability` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html) directly.

Comment: Reachability only help detected network, how to use Reachability detected "No Service" (or mobifone,viettel)?

Comment: Just return it for the case of `NotReachable` - it is the same. Check my edited answer.

Comment: This is Carrier Name in CTCarrier class, use CoreTelephony.framework